# PortfolioAnalytics::SortinoRatio is positive while annualized returns are negative. How can this happen?

Tags: r, r-portfolioanalytics

The result of the SortinoRatio() function from the PortfolioAnalytics package gives a negative annualized return, but a positive Sortino Ratio. The numerator in the Sortino Ratio is annualized return - MAR (set as zero), and the denominator is always positive. Therefore, a negative over a positive should be a negative. So, how can the Sortino Ratio be positive with negative annualized returns (since Downside Deviation is always positive)? Is this a bug, or am I misunderstanding something very basic here? Here is a simplified code to demonstrate:

```
library(PortfolioAnalytics); library(xts)
R <- xts(c(1, 0, -0.99), order.by=c(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-01-02"),as.Date("2018-01-03")))
Return.annualized(R)    # -1
SortinoRatio(R)         # 0.005831821
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is sample size. In Sortino ratio, with your dataset, your end up with a positive Downside Deviation. The reason behind this is because the function eliminates the positive returns (2 out of 3) leaving with one data point that gets squared giving you a positive Downside Deviation. The code in question is result = sqrt(sum((MAR - r)^2/len)) in Downside Deviation.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but my issue is not that Downside Deviation is positive (This is always the case, unless there are no returns below MAR).  I don't think that sample size is the issue, since I got a similar result over a 13 year period of daily returns wherein annualized returns were slightly negative and the Sortino Ratio was positive.